# Build Phase Tab Hidden or Missing

Tags: xcode, tabs

I'm probably asking a very elementary Xcode question, but here it goes. My layout has no 'Build Phase' tab. I might have inadvertently changed my layout.  A lot of tutorials state that you should go to the Build Phase tab and link to a library.  Well, I've Clicked on the Target, and the File under the Target, Searched the Toolbar, searched the project settings, Info.  When I right click on the Target File I get a list including "Copy Build Phase" and Add Build Phase, but that's not giving me access to the Build Phase Tab. I've tried 'reset to default or factory layout'.....Build Phase Tab. How can I display the layout with a Build Phase tab in the toolbar, and save it to utilize in my projects? By the way I'm using XCode 3.2 maybe it's a version limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like those tutorials are for Xcode 4. For your version, if you open the target in the sidebar, there should be some groups. Those are your build phases. Just drag the library into the one that says something like "Link Executable", or click the checkbox to add it to your target and it should go there automatically.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  I had run out of space on my HD. I backed it up then reformatted my harddrive. The 160GB is hardly enough space anymore. Anyway so I lost XCode 4 and of course everything else. Then I forgot I was back down to 3.2 from disc. Just waited through the current new version IOS 5.  I like it already. Next time I fill up my HD and reformatt it, this will come in handy. Thank God for the Terabyte externals.